# Python if_py and VIM: BufAdd, inserting stuff into a new buffer

Tags: python, vim

When I open a buffer (via :tabnew or any other way), if there
is no filename associated with the buffer, I'd like to insert
some default text (recently opened files).

```
au BufAdd * call My_dir(expand("<afile>"))

function! My_dir(fname)
python << EOF
import vim
blah = vim.eval('a:fname')
if str(blah) == 'None':
    cb = vim.current.buffer
    cb.append("yuck")
EOF
endfunction
```

The trouble is that, fname will be 'None' but current.buffer is 
the previous buffer I was in! How do I get the buffer I just 
opened so I can stick stuff in it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the `BufAdd` event is fired before the window is created, and apparently before Vim's current buffer is set to the newly created one.

All you need to do is use the `BufWinEnter` event instead:

```
au BufWinEnter * call My_dir(expand("<afile>"))
```

I tried your function with this small change and it worked.